# In linked list, nodes appear to be overwritten by data in last node

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm in the process of writing a shell for Linux for my Systems Programming class. I've hit a very weird situation in writing a linked list for my command history portion and I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Right now I have the program set up to accept a char array as input and add the data into a node at the end of a linked list and then set that node as the tail of the list. I then have the program print the list from the tail to head. What I should be seeing is the history of what I've typed in, in reverse order. What I am seeing is that what ever I've typed last appears to be overwriting the data in all of the previous nodes.

Eg: I enter 1, I get a 1 printed back, I then enter 2, I get two 2's printed back at me instead of 2 and then a 1. Does anyone know what is going on? My code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define INPUT_BUFFER 255

typedef struct commandHistoryNode commandHistoryNode;

struct commandHistoryNode{
    commandHistoryNode *previous;
    commandHistoryNode *next;
    char *commandLine;
};

commandHistoryNode* AddCommandToLinkedList(commandHistoryNode *, char *);
void PrintLinkedList();
void ExecuteCommand(char *);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char *cmdString;
    cmdString = calloc(INPUT_BUFFER, sizeof(char));
    char *PS1 = "$";
    commandHistoryNode *currentNode = NULL;
    while(1)
    {
        printf(PS1);
        fgets(cmdString, INPUT_BUFFER, stdin);
        //currentNode is the tail of the LinkedList
        currentNode = AddCommandToLinkedList(currentNode, cmdString);

        PrintLinkedList(currentNode);
    }
}

void ExecuteCommand(char *passedCommand){
   return;
}

commandHistoryNode*
AddCommandToLinkedList(commandHistoryNode *passedNode,  char *passedCommand){
    commandHistoryNode *tailNode = malloc(sizeof(commandHistoryNode));
    tailNode->commandLine = passedCommand;
    if(passedNode == NULL)
    {
        //passedNode is the head of the list
        return tailNode;
    }
    else
    {
        while(passedNode->next!=NULL)
        {
            //if passedNode isn't the tail (and it should be), iterate through the list
            passedNode = passedNode->next;
        }
        //set tempNode to the next node for the passedNode
        passedNode->next = tailNode;
        //set the previous node for tempNode to point to the passedNode
        //as it is the new tail.
        tailNode->previous = passedNode;
    }
    //return new tailNode
    return tailNode;
}

void PrintLinkedList(commandHistoryNode *tailNode){
    while(tailNode != NULL)
    {
        printf("command is: %s\n", tailNode->commandLine);
        //iterate backwards from the tail to the head
        tailNode = tailNode->previous;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep re-using the same cmdString for each call to AddCommandToLinkedList.  So every node points to the same character buffer.  As a result, every time you have a new command, you overwrite the one and only character buffer with that command, and every node points to it.  You need to allocate a cmdString for every command, instead of re-using it.

Comment: There's also a logic error in his Add function but I overlooked the buffer reusage. +1 for that.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, and again thank you :). That fixed the problem. I'm look into that logic error too, other than probably not needing the part where I iterate to the end of the list, I haven't seen the error yet. Thank you again!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check again what you return in case passedNode is `!= NULL`.

Comment: Thank you again. If passedNode isn't NULL, then it should take the new node, set the passedNode (which should be the old tail node at this point) and set the next point to point to the new node and the previous pointer in the new node to the old one. The new node should be returned by reference as the new last node on the list. Is it that I should have the return statement in the else block?

Comment: @Andy The logic error is, that you link the tail node to the end of the linked list but return then the tail node was new "head" of the linked list, causing you to "lose" this history.

Comment: @Andy You are also not freeing the memory you allocated. You should change that too